# Multi field validation, obtaining value of another component results in NullPointerException

Tags: validation, jsf, jsf-2.2

I get javax.faces.FacesException: java.lang.NullPointerException when I type something in the zip code and hit submit with country set to default null value. If I select the country and then type something everything works. I tried SubmittedValue, but it is working the opposite way - with null is working and after this is giving null exception.

```
@FacesValidator("zipV")
public class ZipValidator implements Validator {

LocaleBean Bean = new LocaleBean();
String language;
private static final String ZIP_PATTERN_BG = "\\d{4}";
private static final String ZIP_PATTERN_US = "\\d{5}";
private static final String ZIP_PATTERN_DEFAULT = "[A-Za-z0-9]*";
private String zip_pattern;
private Pattern pattern;
private Matcher matcher;
private String country;


@Override
public void validate(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, Object value) throws       ValidatorException {

    language = Bean.getLanguage();

    UIInput Input = (UIInput) component.getAttributes().get("country");
    country = Input.getValue().toString();
    String zip = (String) value;


    if (country == null || country.isEmpty()) {
        return; 
    }

    switch (country) {
        case "BGR":
            zip_pattern = ZIP_PATTERN_BG;
            break;
        case "USA":
            zip_pattern = ZIP_PATTERN_US;
            break;
        default:
            zip_pattern = ZIP_PATTERN_DEFAULT;
            break;
    }

    pattern = Pattern.compile(zip_pattern);

    matcher = pattern.matcher(value.toString());
    if (!matcher.matches()) {


        switch (language) {
            case "en": {
                FacesMessage msg = new FacesMessage("Invalid zip.");
                msg.setSeverity(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR);
                throw new ValidatorException(msg);
            }
            case "bg": {
                FacesMessage msg = new FacesMessage("Невалиден пощенски код.");
                msg.setSeverity(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR);
                throw new ValidatorException(msg);
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

Here's the view:

```
<h:selectOneMenu id="country" value="#{account.country}" required="true" requiredMessage="#{msg['register.required']}" binding="#{country}">
<f:selectItem itemValue="#{null}" itemLabel="#{msg['register.countryQ']}"/>
<f:selectItems value="#{account.countries}"/>
<f:ajax listener="#{account.loadStates()}" render="state"/>
</h:selectOneMenu>

<h:inputText id="zipcode" required="true" requiredMessage="#{msg['register.required']}" value="#{account.zipcode}">
<f:validator validatorId="zipV"/>
<f:attribute name="country" value="#{country}"/>
</h:inputText>
```

Comment: is the null pointer on Input.getValue().toString() ?

Comment: yes, if I change it to SubmittedValue, it is working with null and not working after this.

Comment: could you explain what you mean by 'after this'? do you mean if you use Input.getSubmittedValue().toString() then you don't get the null pointer, but the code doesnt work somewhere after this point?

Comment: I type a value in the zip form, and I click submit - I do not get a nullpointer. I change the country, and I click submit - I get the null pointer.

Comment: The `getSubmittedValue()` is not the right approach. You should only use it if the validator runs *before* the component is been processed. This is not the case here. The validator is running on the zip component *after* the country component is been processed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here,

```
country = Input.getValue().toString();
```

you should not be using `toString()` at all. You should be casting it:

```
country = (String) Input.getValue();
```

Otherwise it will throw `NullPointerException` if the `getValue()` returned `null`. As [its javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/NullPointerException.html) clearly says, a `NullPointerException` will be thrown among others when you attempt to call an instance method on `null` (like as you did with `toString()`).

Please note that this problem is technically unrelated to JSF. It's just basic Java. The `java.lang` package of the exception is a very good hint in this. If you got an exception of `javax.faces` (or `javax.el`) package, then we can talk about a true JSF (or EL) problem.

#### See also:

- [jsf validate two fields in one time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3478133/jsf-validate-two-fields-in-one-time)
- [JSF doesn't support cross-field validation, is there a workaround?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6282466/jsf2-0-doesnt-support-cross-field-validation-is-there-a-workaround)

---

**Unrelated** to the concrete problem, I'd really respect [Java naming conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/codeconventions-135099.html#367). Variable names start with lowercase. Use `input` instead of `Input`. Also, your manual control of localization is strange. What if you ever need to support 10 languages? Do you expand the switches over all place? Make use of JSF builtin localization facilities with `<resource-bundle>` and `ResourceBundle#getBundle()`.

Comment: thanks this helped. How can I make my ResourceBundle#getBundle() to get the bundle from com.program.messages instead of the root folder.

Comment: Just pass exactly that value as base name.

Comment: I tried it does not work. It works only if they are called messages.properties in the root and the value is messages. ResourceBundle.getBundle("messages", currentLocale). I also tried com/program/messsages/messages... it does not work