# jsf calendar return unexpected (wrong?) value

Tags: jsf, primefaces, jsf-2

I have a primefaces calendar with a validator attached to it.

```
<p:calendar id="validationTriggeringCalendar"
            label="other calendar"
            value="#{myBean.otherDate}"
            navigator="true"
            locale="de"
            pattern="dd.MM.yyyy"
            showOn="button"
            renderAsPopup="true"
            required="true"
            size="12">
    <f:validator validatorId="packagename.DateFromToValidator" />
</p:calendar>
<p:calendar id="myCalendar"
            label="Some Date"
            value="#{myBean.someDate}"
            navigator="true"
            effect=""
            locale="de"
            pattern="dd.MM.yyyy"
            showOn="button"
            renderAsPopup="true"
            mindate="#{myBean.mindate}"
            size="12">
</p:calendar>
```

Inside the validator I get the calendar UI component `myCalendar`(the one that did not trigger the validation) and call the `getValue()` method, which does not return the value that is entered into it.

I debugged the validator code entering the date "10.10.2009":

```
UIInput calendar = getMeTheCalendar();
Date date = (Date) calendar.getValue();
```

My debugger even tells me the value of the `submittedValue` attribute of the `calendar` is "10.10.2009", exactly what I entered and what is displayed in my browser. But the `getValue()` method returns a date object `Thu Oct 10 00:00:00 CEST 2019`.
How do I get the entered value of the component?

I use Primefaces 5.3.1 btw.

Comment: While debugging, what does the third parameter of your `validate` method tell you? The Calendar.getValue() will return the entered date when models have been update **after** the successful validation phase.

Comment: Ok, but how can I validate the input, if it is just accessible by the validator after validation?

Comment: Are you sure `myCalendar` is **above** the validated calendar? Looks like element order matters: [jsf validate two fields in one time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3478133/jsf-validate-two-fields-in-one-time)

Comment: No the calendar, that triggers the validation is `validationTriggeringCalendar`. But I lookup `myCalendar` by its id and try to get its value.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JSF doesn't support cross-field validation, is there a workaround?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6282466/jsf-doesnt-support-cross-field-validation-is-there-a-workaround)

Comment: Yes I understand that - when looking at your example code, your `myCalendar` is declared above the validated `validationTriggeringCalendar`. Is that also true for the source code in your actual  application you see in your IDE? If so, myCalendar.getValue() **should** return the entered value as it can be read in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3478409/865107).

Comment: No the order of the two calendars is changed: the `myCalendar` is actually declared above the `validationTriggeringCalendar`. I'm gonna correct this.

Comment: So then you basically know how to solve this, right?

Comment: Yes, the hint with the order of declaration and the link for the possible duplicate gave me the right direction, that there is a getSubmittedValue() method and which method to use in what case.